# Regex to Capture last email Address

Tags: regex, exchange-server

I need a regex to capture last email addresss

> 2017-11-30T17:00:02.596Z,10.1.20.211,RenjuXXX,X.X.X.X,mxa-0003fe01.xx.renjj.com,;250 2.0.0 2ej1k6mass-1 Message accepted for delivery;ClientSubmitTime:,Outbound to Internet,SMTP,SEND,asadasdasd1212,,b4b8c0b5-ce3b-4aca-8335-08d53813c96a,Jose.renj@renj.org,250 2.1.5 Recipient ok,41758,1,,,RE: my CV,renjujacob@renju.com,renjujacob@renju.com,

I tried using this regex below to capture the email ID , but its capturing the first [email](https://regex101.com/r/JiHHMr/1)

> ((?P(?<=,)[a-zA-Z0-9-*.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-*.]+(?=\s*(?:\w+=|,))))

need a regex to capture last email id (renjujacob@renju.com). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is after the last comma? The end of the string?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
[^,\s@]++@[^,\s@]++(?![^@]*@)
```

---

Broken down, this says:

```
[^,\s@]++    # NOT comma nor whitespace nor @, 1+ times, possessive
@            # @ literally
[^,\s@]++    # same as above
(?![^@]*@)   # a neg. lookahead, making sure there's no @ to follow
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/KdVKMh/4).

---

An alternative approach would be to grab all email addresses via

```
[^,\s@]++@[^,\s@]++
```

and select the last item in your programming language (e.g. `results[-1]` in `Python`).

### Edit:

Thanks to @Andrei for ameliorating the pattern.

Comment: Does it make sense to add `@` to `[^,\s]` for faster processing?

Comment: @AndreiOdegov: Of course, have updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*((?<=,)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(?=\s*(?:\w+=|,)))
```

.* matches any character (except for line terminators)

- Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) [this greediness allows to return the LAST occurrence for group 1]

1st Capturing Group ((?<=,)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(?=\s*(?:\w+=|,))) :

Positive Lookbehind (?<=,)

Assert that the Regex below matches

, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+

- Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)

A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

-. matches a single character in the list -. (case sensitive)

@ matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)

Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+:

- Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)

A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

-. matches a single character in the list -. (case sensitive)
Positive Lookahead (?=\s*(?:\w+=|,))

Assert that the Regex below matches:

\s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

Non-capturing group (?:\w+=|,)

Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after the first match)

https://regex101.com/r/nWgDSy/1

Answer (score 0):

The regex

```
,([^,@]+@[^,@]),[^,]*$
```

captures inside the parentheses an email address from the penultimate comma-separated field without a lot of (very often false) assumptions about what an email address can or cannot contain - we require exactly one `@` and rule out commas because the format is comma-separated, but that's it.